# DOS-CSV import via C# and German Umlaute (Ä,Ü,Ö,ä,ü,ö)

Tags: c#, excel, csv, utf-8

I have the following problem: I have some **Excel-sheets** and must export them into **DOS-CSV** format (for some reasons). The consequence is, that the german umlaute **(Ä,Ü,Ö,ä,ü,ö)** are not exported correctly. In a next step these CSV-files must be imported into a **Winform application**. Is it now possible to get back the correkt characters Ä,Ü,Ö,ä,ü,ö during the import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose the DOS-CSV format, Excel is going to encode the document using the 437 codepage ([found that here](https://superuser.com/questions/385265/whats-the-difference-between-csv-ms-dos-csv-macintosh-csv-comma-delimi)). You can convert it back to UTF-8 using a little bit of code:

```
Encoding dosEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
string original = String.Empty;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Path\To\output.csv", dosEncoding))
{
    original = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}

byte[] encBytes = dosEncoding.GetBytes(original);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(dosEncoding, Encoding.UTF8, encBytes);

string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

I tested this by putting `Ä,Ü,Ö,ä,ü,ö` into a cell and then saving it as a DOS formatted CSV file in Excel. Looking at the document, Excel turned it into `Ž,š,™,„,,”`.

Running it through the above code turned it back into `Ä,Ü,Ö,ä,ü,ö`.